# Replace dash by underscore prometheus query

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have this promQL: `avg(increase(vault_route_create_${mountpoint}__count[5m]))`

The `${mountpoint}` value sometimes contains dash, then this is a possible metric name: `vault_route_create_my-value__count`.

But the metric is always with underscore, then the correct would be `vault_route_create_my_value__count`.

Well, I can't change the value of `mountpoint` variable, it is loaded by a different source. I would like to replace the dash by underscore in query if is possible, something like that:

`avg(increase(vault_route_create_${replace_dash(${mountpoint})}__count[5m]))`

Any tips here?

Comment: Where are you using this PromQL? Grafana? A script? Why you can't change the value?

Comment: I'm using PromQL into grafana dashboards. I can't change the metric value because I don't have control who is sending it.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to find via google I will mention that this question is related to Grafana Dashboards for Vault.

We encountered the same problem as our mountpoints where using slashes.
The issue can be somewhat "solved" by using a combination of clever variable querying and regex filtering.

We use the following query to extract the labels in the correct form, I already adapted it for your use-case, you simply have to adjust the regex in case you have a different source format for the mountpoints:

```
query_result(label_replace(vault_secret_kv_count, "mount_point", "${1}_$2", "mount_point", "(.*?)-(.*?)/"))
```

And then filter the results using the following regex:

```
/.*mount_point="([^"]*).*/
```

If you configure all of this in the mountpoint variable the dashboard should work as expected.